# Which Uncle Ben was more true to the original Spider-Man comics?

Tags: spider-man, adaptation-comparison, marvel, the-amazing-spider-man

I watched the *Spider-Man* series with Toby Maguire and now I'm watching *The Amazing Spider-Man*.

I don't really know enough to know which one is most "authentic" but as I'm watching this newer version of Spider-Man somehow I get the feeling that it's less true to the original story. Am I correct?

In the Toby Maguire Spider-Man, to the best of my memory, Uncle Ben was murdered by a carjacker exiting Peter's boxing match as Ben tried to talk him out of his crime. In *The Amazing Spider-Man* a thief grabs money from a cash register then stumbles in front of Ben, who then tries to steal the thief's gun, and Ben is shot in the ensuing struggle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Wikipedia:

> In high school, a radioactive spider bite gave Peter superhuman powers. Creating the costumed identity of Spider-Man for himself, Peter sought first to exploit his newfound powers as a masked wrestler and then as a television star. Coming from a television appearance, Spider-Man saw a burglar[5] being chased by a security guard. The guard called for Spider-Man to stop the thief, but the nascent Spidey refused on the grounds that catching criminals was not his job. The robber got away.[6]
>
> When Peter later returned home, he was informed by a police officer that his beloved Uncle Ben had been killed by a burglar. Outraged, he donned his Spider-Man costume and captured the man only to realize to his horror that it was the same burglar whom he could have effortlessly captured earlier at the studio. As a result, Peter considered himself morally responsible for Ben's death and resolved to fight crime as a superhero — realizing that with great power comes great responsibility — and vowing never to let another innocent person come to harm if he could help it

Looks like neither is spot on, but the Tobey McGuire version was closer.

Comment: Many thanks. I upvoted it, though I think it would probably be better to cite the original sources instead of Wikipedia..

Comment: The Tobey Maguire version is very close. They just added Peter being there when Uncle Ben died to add to the impact. Uncle Ben didn't have much screen time, so it was probably a good idea.

Comment: Well, that and it was at a pro wrestling 'open cage match' kind of thing rather than a television appearance, and a few other things.